# Formula for a repeating sequence of 5 integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a repeating sequence of 5 integers...

$$\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
n:&      1,& 2,& 3,& 4,& 5,& 6,& 7,& 8,& 9,& 10,& ...\\
f(n):&  -2,& 1,& 0,& -1,& 2,& -2,& 1,& 0,& -1,& 2,&  ...
\end{array}
$$

I need a function that generates these sequence values.  eg: $f(6) = -2$

If there were **only $3$** repeating integers  (say $-2, 1, 0, -2, 1, 0$...), I could solve for $A$, $B$, and $C$ in

$$\begin{align}
f(1) =   A  + \sin(1\times2\pi/3)*B  +  \cos(1\times2\pi/3)*C  &=  -2\\
f(2) =   A  + \sin(2\times2\pi/3)*B  +  \cos(2\times2\pi/3)*C  &=   1\\
f(3) =   A  + \sin(3\times2\pi/3)*B  +  \cos(3\times2\pi/3)*C  &=   0
\end{align} $$

But, with $5$ repeating integers, I'm having trouble setting up the $5$ equations.  I would use the coefficients  $\sin(n\times 2\pi/5)$ and $\cos(n\times 2\pi/5))$, but I suspect each function needs $5$ terms (in $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $E$).  Any clues how to set this up?

Answer (score 2):

How about 
$$
f(n) = (((n-1) \bmod 5) - 2) \, (-1)^{((n-1) \bmod 5) \bmod 2}
$$

Which means shift the argument by one, then going into a modulo 5 cycle, shifting the values by $-2$. Modulating the whole with with those funny minus signs for the positions $1$ and $3$ (in contrast to $0$, $2$, $4$).

I told my friend Ruby about it

```
def f(n)
  k = (n-1) % 5
  (k-2) * (-1)**(k % 2)
end

(1..20).each do |k|
  puts "#{k}: #{f(k)}"
end
```

and she replied with:

```
1: -2
2: 1
3: 0
4: -1
5: 2
6: -2
7: 1
8: 0
9: -1
10: 2
11: -2
12: 1
13: 0
14: -1
15: 2
16: -2
17: 1
18: 0
19: -1
20: 2
```

Comment: Very innovative solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would use
$$
f(n)=g(n\ \text{mod } 5)
$$
where $g:\{0,1,2,3,4\}\to\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ with
$$
g(1)-2,\ g(2)=1, g(3)=0, g(4)=-1,g(0)=2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Try including $\sin(n\times4\pi/5)$ and $\cos(n\times4\pi/5)$.  These are the upcoming terms in the Fourier series.

Solving the system we then get

$$f(x) = 0 -0.145\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}x\right)+0.106\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}x\right)-0.616\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}x\right)+1.894\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}x\right)$$

Or approximately.  I haven't found nice closed form solutions for the coefficients; they may yet exist but I don't know what they are.  (I do know that the paired coefficients for each frequency give a sine wave with a zero point at $x=3$ but that's all I've got)

Here that is, plotted.

[image: sine interpolation of five points]

Comment: You can always write the coefficients in terms of exponentials.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found good ones yet.  I ran the numbers through sage and  it's utterly nasty.  The inverted matrix runs to 85k characters.

Comment: Thank you - this was a big help.

Comment: For what it's worth, here are the actual coefficients for Dan Uznanski's function given above... 

f(x)= a + b*Sin(2π5x) + c*cos(2π5x) _ d*sin(4π5x) + e*cos(4π5x)

where   a = 0,      c = (5 - 2*sqr(5))/5,      e = (5 + 2*sqr(5))/5

        b = [ sqr(10 - 2*sqr(5))  -  sqr(10 + 2*sqr(5))]/10

        d = [-sqr(10 - 2*sqr(5))  +  sqr(10 + 2*sqr(5))]/10

Answer (score 2):

If you allow yourself the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) then
$$
f(n) = (-1)^{n+1 - 5 \lfloor (n/5 \rfloor} \left( n - 3 - 5\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{5} \right\rfloor \right)
$$
does the job.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(-1)^{n+1-5\lfloor n/5 \rfloor}(n-3-5\lfloor (n-1)/5 \rfloor$ - equivalent to @mvw's answer?

Comment: @BalarkaSen Thanks for your vigilance - but I've no problem with people improving my answers (even without private permission). I think that makes the site better. Pretty soon Zara will have enough rep so that his edits don't go on the review queue.

Comment: @EthanBolker Duly noted. A comment by the author below the post might be helpful for avoiding further inconvenience from the reviewers in general.